# Application not launching or calling onNewIntent when notification clicked

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm successfully sending notifications using GCM, but when I click on them, nothing happens.  Here is the code in my listener, I can verify that it is executing, but when I put breakpoints on the `onCreate` and `onNewIntent` methods in my `HomeActivity` they are never hit.  In addition, if that application is not running, I still receive the notification, but the application is not launched.  I have tried suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14609666/567547) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27431086/567547) as well as several different combinations of Intent flags.  Am I missing something?  Please ask if you need me to post more code.

Code from my `GcmListenerService`

```
    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(appNameID))
            .setContentText(payload)
            .setSmallIcon(iconID)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), bigIconID));

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(HomeActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID_KEY, notificationID);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    resultIntent.setAction(HomeActivity.NOTIFICATION_ACTION);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
    int defaults = 0;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);


    // Post a notification
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Anything interesting in the logcat?

Comment: I just finished combing through the output and yes, when I click on the notifications, I'm getting `Unable to send startActivity intent
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial`

Comment: post your AndroidManifest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you added **android:launchMode="singleTop"** in your manifest. and also add **intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP**

**UPDATED**

Aadd **android:exported="true"** to your manifest, That might solve your problem.

Comment: `add android:exported="true"` this fixed it.  I add that to the `activity` node for my `HomeActivity` and it started working.  Thanks!